# getting java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, linked-list

I was implementing Graph data structure in Java. 
Here is my implementation:

```
    package Graph;

    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

   public class Graphs
   {
       int size;
       LinkedList<Integer>[] ll;

       Graphs(int size)
       {
            this.size = size;

            ll = new LinkedList[size];

            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
              ll[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();

       }

       public static void print(LinkedList lli)
       {
            for(Integer i: lli)
                System.out.println(i);

            //for(int i=0; i<lli.size(); i++)
            //    System.out.println(lli.get(i));
       }

       public static void addEdge(Graphs graph, int up, int to)
       {
           graph.ll[to].add(up);
       }

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
          int V=5;
          Graphs graph = new Graphs(V);

          addEdge(graph,1,2);
          addEdge(graph,1,3);
          addEdge(graph,2,3);
          addEdge(graph,3,1);
          addEdge(graph,3,2);
          addEdge(graph,3,4);
          addEdge(graph,4,3);

          print(graph.ll[3]);      
      }

   }
```

Basically I am creating an array of LinkedLists for the graph with each linked list for a vertex of the  graph.

However, I am getting a java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer at line number 24. Clueless as to why am I getting this error. Any suggestions as to what am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't the construct from Graph contain this.ll (similar to this.size)? Please post the complete error stack the problem isn't resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue you're having is with your print function:

```
public static void print(LinkedList lli){
        for(Integer i: lli)
            System.out.println(i);
}
```

`LinkedList` is a raw type, meaning you lose type information about what kinds of objects are stored in the list. As a general rule, [raw types are a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). I'm very surprised your code compiled, but suffice to say that by saying `Integer i : lli` you're assumming that every object within `lli` is an `Integer` when the parameter `LinkedList` provides no such guarantee.

To ensure that this will work, change `LinkedList lli` to `LinkedList<Integer> lli`. This means that every object in lli is an instance of Integer, thus the iteration won't fail.

When I try to run your code, my IDE warns me about the line

```
ll = new LinkedList[size]
```

Saying:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.LinkedList[]' to 'java.util.LinkedList< java.lang.Integer >[]'

Which indicates that something fishy is going on here.

Mixing Lists and Arrays gets a bit messy with generic typing - it's a lot easier and cleaner to just do lists of lists if you need size mutability, or a multi-dimension array if not. For your case, that argues for a `ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>` or the like.

We can fix the issues by resolving the generic issues:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Graphs
{
  int size;
  ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> ll;

  Graphs(int size)
  {
    this.size = size;

    ll = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      ll.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());

  }

  public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> lli)
  {
    for(Integer i: lli)
      System.out.println(i);

    //for(int i=0; i<lli.size(); i++)
    //    System.out.println(lli.get(i));
  }

  public static void addEdge(Graphs graph, int up, int to)
  {
    graph.ll.get(to).add(up);
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int V=5;
    Graphs graph = new Graphs(V);

    addEdge(graph,1,2);
    addEdge(graph,1,3);
    addEdge(graph,2,3);
    addEdge(graph,3,1);
    addEdge(graph,3,2);
    addEdge(graph,3,4);
    addEdge(graph,4,3);

    print(graph.ll.get(3));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot. That really helped :)

Comment: While you are right about the unchecked assignment and your code does compile, it was not the actual problem.. It would have been enough to change the method signature to `print(LinkedList<Integer> lli)`

Comment: Ah yeah, now I see it. In any case, fully resolving the generics issues does address it. Updated

Answer (score 1):

Declare the print method like this:

```
public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> lli)
```

Then it will know that the contents of lli are integers.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it didn't compile until I changed

```
public static void print(LinkedList lli)
```

to:

```
public static void print(LinkedList<Integer> lli)
```

From where it worked without problems

Also giving variables a name which starts with an upper case letter is against the naming convention. Have a look at [this oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). The last bullet point on the page states:

> If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word, capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word. The names gearRatio and currentGear are prime examples of this convention.